# Textractor python library - Is there a way to export key values in reading order to csv?

Tags: python, amazon-textract

I'm currently trying to use the textractor python library (https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-textractor/) to process a pdf using Amazon Textract.

I've been able to call the API and return results using the library but exporting the key values does not seem to have any specific logical order.

I'm trying to process a multi-page application form which has multiple fields with the same key (e.g Yes/No) and was hoping to use the order to identify which belongs to which question.

Script below:

```
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures

extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")
document = extractor.start_document_analysis(
    file_source=("Application Form trimmed.pdf"),
    features=[TextractFeatures.FORMS],
    s3_upload_path="s3://textractbucket2/"
)
document.export_kv_to_csv(
    include_kv=True,
    include_checkboxes=True,
    filepath="async_kv.csv"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.0.16 (pip install amazon-textract-textractor==1.0.16) should address this issue. The entities are sorted by their page then Y,X coordinates which should preserve the ordering of your keys and values.

However, depending on the number of questions that you have, Queries might be a better fit (and cheaper). You can "ask" up to 15 questions like this:

```
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures

extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")
document = extractor.start_document_analysis(
    file_source=("Application Form trimmed.pdf"),
    features=[TextractFeatures.QUERIES],
    queries=[
        "What is X?",
        "What is Y?",
        # Up to 15 questions here
    ],
    s3_upload_path="s3://textractbucket2/"
)

print(document.queries)
```

See the documentation for more details: https://aws-samples.github.io/amazon-textract-textractor/notebooks/using_queries.html